# Initialize and get struct variables in another struct?

Tags: c, linux, struct, tree, binary-search-tree

Hey guys I have two structs: one is a key-pair and the other is a node.

```
typedef struct {
    char *key;
    void *value;
} VL;

typedef struct node{
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    VL data;
} BST;
```

How would I go about initializing the node struct and adding the VL struct inside?
This is what I have so far:

```
    // Create new node
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;

    struct VL *vl = malloc(sizeof(VL));
    vl->key = key;
    vl->value = &value;

    temp->data= *vl;
```

And I've also tried many other things like setting temp->data.key to key etc, all of which return errors. So I've come here for help :).

Also how would I go about getting the data from the nodes?

```
char *key = (char *)5;
void *val = "hello";
// create node with this key/val pair and insert into the tree, then print
printf("key = %d; value = %s\n", (int)head->data.key, (char*)head->data.value);
```

Would that suffice?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to output the `key` as an integer in your final `printf`? What is the desired output? That statement is hard to read and somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory for `VL data` is allocated as part of the `node` struct and does not need to be reallocated.

Try:

```
struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->left = NULL;
temp->right = NULL;
(temp->data).key = key;
(temp->data).value = &value;
```